# Pseudo element in jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After clicking div **width** going to **50%** with animate, I appended a circle with pseudo, but when the animation is playing it is hiding. I also tried with a span inside div instead of pseudo elements, but no success. Any idea?

```js
$('a').click(function() {
    $('div').animate({
    width: 50 + "%"
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

div span {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -2px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>

<a>click</a>
```

I don't want hide the circle when the animation is playing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `overflow: initial !important;` for the `div`

```js
$('a').click(function(){
$('div').animate({

width: 50 + "%"
}, 2000);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: initial !important;
}

div span {
    display:inline-block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -2px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span></span>
</div>

<a>click</a>
```

Comment: alright, thanks for answer but can you explain more to clear what was the problem?

Comment: animate adds overflow hidden when in animation so your dot is hidden by the overflow

Comment: that's right, `animate` function adds `overflow:hidden`, so you have to override it by `overflow: inherit !important;`

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `transition` and let CSS do the animation.

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<a>click</a>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $("div").css("width", "50%");
});
```

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $("div").css("width", "50%");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
   transition: 2s;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

<a>click</a>
```

Comment: This is a cleaner answer I think